# ZF2 router configuration for subdomain with child routes

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-route

I need my router configuration to work as follows:

```
www.bmob.co.uk           -> DtCompanyData\Controller\CompanyMap   
wage.bmob.co.uk          -> DtWage\Controller\Wage  
wage.bmob.co.uk/brighton -> DtWage\Controller\WageBrighton
```

After reading the documentation and many similar questions on here, I can get the routing to work either for the subdomain, or for the child routes, but not both at the same time.

When I have

```
// In Application/config/module.config.php:

'home' => array(
    'type' => 'hostname',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => 'www.bmob.co.uk',
        'defaults' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DtCompanyData\Controller',
            'controller' => 'DtCompanyData\Controller\CompanyMap',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),

// In DtWage/config/module.config.php:

'wage' => array(
    'type' => 'hostname',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => 'wage.bmob.co.uk',
        'defaults' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DtWage\Controller',
            'controller' => 'DtWage\Controller\Wage',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
),
```

I get:

```
www.bmob.co.uk - works  
wage.bmob.co.uk - works  
wage.bmob.co.uk/brighton - goes to same page as wage.bmob.co.uk
```

When I have:

```
// In Application/config/module.config.php:

'home' => array(
    'type' => 'hostname',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => 'www.bmob.co.uk',
        'defaults' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DtCompanyData\Controller',
            'controller' => 'DtCompanyData\Controller\CompanyMap',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),

// In DtWage/config/module.config.php:

'wage' => array(
    'type' => 'hostname',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => 'wage.bmob.co.uk',
        'defaults' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DtWage\Controller',
            'controller' => 'DtWage\Controller\Wage',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'wagebrighton' => array( 
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/brighton',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DtWage\Controller',   // Have also tried without this line, same result
                    'controller' => 'DtWage\Controller\WageBrighton',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

I get:

```
www.bmob.co.uk - works  
wage.bmob.co.uk - 404 The requested URL could not be matched by routing.  
wage.bmob.co.uk/brighton - works
```

What am I doing wrong here? How to I get wage.bmob.co.uk and wage.bmob.co.uk/brighton to both work at the same time? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try two configurations :

```
'wage' => array(
    'type' => 'hostname',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => 'wage.bmob.co.uk/',
        'defaults' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DtWage\Controller',
            'controller' => 'DtWage\Controller\Wage',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'wagebrighton' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/brighton',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DtWage\Controller', // Have also tried without this line, same result
                    'controller' => 'DtWage\Controller\WageBrighton',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

or

```
'wage' => array(
    'type' => 'hostname',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => 'wage.bmob.co.uk',
        'defaults' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DtWage\Controller',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => false,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'wagehome' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DtWage\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'DtWage\Controller\Wage',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'wagebrighton' => array(
                    'type' => 'literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/brighton',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DtWage\Controller',
                            'controller' => 'DtWage\Controller\WageBrighton',
                            'action' => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

EDIT : what about this one :

```
'wage' => array(
    'type' => 'hostname',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => 'wage.bmob.co.uk',
        'defaults' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DtWage\Controller',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => false,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'wagehome' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DtWage\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'DtWage\Controller\Wage',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'wagebrighton' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/brighton',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'DtWage\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'DtWage\Controller\WageBrighton',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: The first one gave me errors, but the second one was closer.  I see what you're getting at with the child routes.  The second one gives me the right page for `wage.bmob.co.uk` but for `wage.bmob.co.uk/brighton` I get another 404 The requested URL could not be matched by routing.